# Is there a way to detect mouse released on another JLabel?

Tags: java, user-interface, jlabel

Hello suppose I have two different JLabels with two different MouseListeners implemented.

What I want is to press mouse on Label1 and return true if I release it on Label2, otherwise false.

Is there any way to do it? I was trying hasFocus() method and many more but none of them did what I need.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible with MouseListener / MouseMotionListeners.

Comment: It's possible if both of the labels are class attributes, but I wouldn't recommend this...

Comment: Well the thing is: I have a JPanel and in the JPanel i have a grid of JLabels and I want to make a drag move and it would depend on which Label i release the mouse. I guess it is a bad idea but it seemed easier than messing around with mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using MVC: it's its exact purpose!

This tutorial is quite simple and well explained: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm